# SQL. How to find out what times overlap?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with variables startTime and duration, is it possible to find out what times in this table overlap without having the ending time?

Comment: The ending time is just `startTime + duration`. So you can use the same algorithm that would be used with an ending time, but use that value in its place.

Comment: See [overlap](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/overlap/info) tag.

Comment: @RIPJUICE . . . If you haven't figure this out, then ask a *new* question (and delete this one).  Add sample data, desired results, and the version of MySQL that you are using.